# parse String color without java

Tags: java

i have a code like this :

```
String hex = String.format("0x%02x%02x%02x", r * 0.5, green * 0.6, blue * 0.7));
```

0.5 and 0.6 and 0.7 are variables
and i want to set background color of a view from variable hex :

```
v.setBackgroundColor(Integer.parseInt(hex, 16));
```

When i try to convert it to Hexadecimal integer it throws exceptions like

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException
```

how can i do this?

Comment: There are many things that could have gone wrong. Please provide us more code so we can help you

Comment: I dont have any idea i just want to convert String to hexadecimal integer and then set background color with that integer

Comment: Can you derive what String hex contains...?

Answer (score 2):

`0x` causes `NumberFormatException`. try `Integer.decode` instead:

```
v.setBackgroundColor(Integer.decode(hex));
```

Read:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#decode(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

There are potentially three problems with this code:

1. As @shiftpsh notes: `Integer.parseInt` does not understand the `0x` prefix.  There are two ways to solve this:

   - Use `Integer.decode` rather that `Integer.parseInt`.
   - Don't include the `0x` prefix in the format.
2. The second *potential* problem is that `%02x` means hexadecimal, zero-padded with a **minimum** of two digits.  But if any of `r`, `green` or `blue` were large enough, the resulting color value would be greater than 255, and you would get more than 2 hex digits.  That would result in an incorrect RGB value when the string is decoded.
3. I am rather surprised that `%02x` works for an argument like `r * 0.5`.  The latter is a `double` and *according to my reading of the javadoc* the `x` conversion is not applicable.

---

However, if the sole point of this code is to create and RGB value from `r`, `green` and `blue`, there is a significantly more efficient way to do it.

```
 int r0 = ((int)(r * 0.5)) & 0xff;
 int g0 = ((int)(green * 0.6)) & 0xff;
 int b0 = ((int)(blue * 0.7)) & 0xff;
 v.setBackgroundColor((r0 << 16) | (g0 << 8) | b0);
```

Alternatively, using `android.graphics.Color.argb` to do the RGB conversion should be just as efficient .... though that is an Android API rather than a Java API.  (I could not find a directly equivalent Java SE library method that is as efficient.)